# Writing an algorithm in LaTeX

Tags: indentation, algorithms, algorithmicx

[image]

I am trying to write an algorithm in LaTeX. I used a `for` loop inside the algorithm (see attached image), but the problem is that the statements that are below the `for` loop are not tapped. Why?

I used the packages `\usepackage{algorithm}` and `\usepackage{algpseudocode}`.

This the code I wrote:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{CH election algorithm}
\label{CHalgorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{CH\textendash Election} {}
\For{each node $i$ \Pisymbol{psy}{206} $N$ }
\\Broadcast HELLO message to its neighbor
\\let $k$ \Pisymbol{psy}{206} $N1$ ($i$) U {$i$} be s.t
\\QOS($k$) = max {QOS($j$) \textbar $j$ \Pisymbol{psy}{206} $N1$($i$)  U $i$}
\\ MPRSet($i$) = $k$
\EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Any reason why you use `$i$ \Pisymbol{psy}{206} $N$` instead of just `$i \in N$`?

Answer (score 22):

You have to use `\State` instead of `\\` to indent your lines inside the `\For` statement.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{CH election algorithm}
\label{CHalgorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{CH\textendash Election}{}
\For{each node $i$ \Pisymbol{psy}{206} $N$ }
\State Broadcast HELLO message to its neighbor
\State let $k$ \Pisymbol{psy}{206} $N1$ ($i$) U {$i$} be s.t
\State QOS($k$) = max {QOS($j$) \textbar $j$ \Pisymbol{psy}{206} $N1$($i$)  U $i$}
\State MPRSet($i$) = $k$
\EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]